# Detecting phone within an area

Tags: android, geolocation

I need to detect whether my phone (android) has entered a particular area on a map - the area is about 300m x 300m.

Once I've got a position for the phone, I'm able to do the math (that seems to be the easy part!),  I'm just not sure what the best strategy is for following the phone and getting regular updates.  This is what I have so far:

An AlarmManager sets off every (currently) 1 minute...I'll up this to about 10 minutesish or more.
The AlarmManager checks whether a location, younger than 15 minutes, is available from any provider (GPS or NETWORK)
If there is no location available, or it is older than 15 minutes, it will request a single update.

I have this:

```
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
```

...that's likely to pick up the NETWORK provider isn't it?  Which doesn't appear to be tooo precise at the moment, it's currently placing my phone half way down the road.

This *may* be the wrong strategy.  Within the 300m x 300m area there are Wifi Access points, and a bluetooth point - can I use these to detect that the phone is nearby?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [ProximityAlert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) for this.

It allows you to define a location on the map (latitude and longitude) and a radius. If you enter or exit the defined area, an intent is sent. You can catch this intent and use it in your application.

Comment: I've had a look at ProximityAlert but I'm lead to believe it's a real hungry battery eater - appears to rely quite heavily on GPS which isn't so great.  Have you had any experience with this and running it, essentially, all day?

Comment: Locating your device is always (more or less) energy consuming. If you want to wait for tens of minutes befoe you update your fix, you might need to implement your own solution. Remember, however, that the proximity alert works independend of your app and you do not need to keep your app / service running in the background.